# Satisfiable CNFs where each clause contains logarithmically many different literals

Tags: complexity-theory, logic, probability-theory, polynomial-time

Studying for my finals in Complexity theory. This question comes up in different variants and it requires to use probability.

A side note before, to be more clear: A CNF clause consists of $n$ clauses
$C_i$, so $\varphi=C_1\wedge\dots \wedge C_n$, and each $C_i$ has some amount of literals $l_1^i,\ldots ,l_m^i$, so $C_i=l_1^i\vee\dots \vee l_m^i$, and each $l_i$ is some variable $x$ or its negation $\lnot x$.

> Let $L$ consist of all satisfiable CNFs $\varphi$ such that each clause of $\varphi$ contains at least $\log_{2}\left(|\varphi|\right)$ different literals.
>
> Prove that $L\in P$.

I know that we could write a Turing machine $M$ on $\langle \varphi\rangle$ go over each clause in $\varphi$ and count the number of literals. If it's less than $\log_2\left(|\varphi|\right)$ then reject. Otherwise accept. Of course this machine is polynomial. But we need to prove: $L(M)=L$.

Over the course, they showed a way to use probability. A similar question was given:

> Given a 3CNF clause $\varphi$ **in which every clause consists of different variables**, at least $\frac{7}{8}$ of the clauses can be satisfied simultaneously.
>
> This idea was used to prove that the language $L'$ of all $\varphi\in 3SAT$ in which each clause contains different variables such that there exist an assignment that satisfies $7/8$ of the clauses is in $P$.

So I tried to prove my main task and I would love some feedback.

We want to calculate the probability of $\varphi\in CNF$ so each clause in it, contains **exactly** $\log_{2}\left(|\varphi|\right)$ literals, to be satisfied.

We will define a probability space where each assignment for $\varphi$'s variables is selected with a uniform probability. For each clause $C_k$ we will define the following indicator:
$$
\mathbb{I}_{k}\triangleq\begin{cases}
1 & z\left(C_{k}\right)=T\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
So we get:
$$
E\left(\mathbb{I}_{k}\right)=0\cdot P\left(\mathbb{I}_{k}=0\right)+1\cdot P\left(\mathbb{I}_{k}=1\right)=P\left(\mathbb{I}_{k}=1\right)
$$
Let's calculate the probability of $P\left(\mathbb{I}_{k}=1\right)$. Let's look at $C_{k}=\left(l_{1}^{k}\vee\ldots\vee l_{\log_{2}\left(|\varphi|\right)}^{k}\right)$ where **all the literals are independent** and we will calculate the probability of $z$ being $z\left(C_{k}\right)=T$.

Let's define $\Omega$ to be all the possibilities. So we get $|\Omega|=2^{\log_{2}\left(|\varphi|\right)}=|\varphi|$ (since the literals are independent).

Let's define $A$ to be all the possibilities so we get true. This means that at least one of the literals should return true. So we get $|A|=|\varphi|-1$.

Since this is an equal probability space we will get:
$$
P\left(A\right)=\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{|\varphi|-1}{|\varphi|}
$$

Now we get $P\left(A\right)\leq P\left(\mathbb{I}_{k}=1\right)$ (since literals are not necessarily independent). Then we get:
$$
E\left(\mathbb{I}_{k}\right)=P\left(\mathbb{I}_{k}=1\right)\geq\frac{|\varphi|-1}{|\varphi|}
$$
Lets mark $t$ to be the number of clauses in $\varphi$. Also, lets mark $X=\sum_{k=1}^{t}\mathbb{I}_{k}$ So we get:
$$
E\left(X\right)=E\left(\sum_{k=1}^{t}\mathbb{I}_{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{t}E\left(\mathbb{I}_{k}\right)\geq\sum_{k=1}^{t}\frac{|\varphi|-1}{|\varphi|}=\frac{|\varphi|-1}{|\varphi|}t=t\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{|\varphi|}\right)
$$

From this we can conclude that there is necessarily an assignment that satisfies $t$ clauses from $\varphi$ and therefore it satisfies $\varphi$, i.e. $\varphi \in SAT$.

Since this question comes very often in the finals, I want to make sure I understand each step. So the things I'm not sure about:

1. I'm not sure that my statement of $P\left(A\right)\leq P\left(\mathbb{I}_{k}=1\right)$ is being true. I'm not sure how to calculate the probability if the literals are not independent. From the question, they should be different, but I could have $x$ and $\lnot x$ in the same clause, and they are of course dependent.
2. The question asks about "at least $\log_{2}\left(|\varphi|\right)$" and I talked about "exactly $\log_{2}\left(|\varphi|\right)$".
3. What do I actually get out of proving that $E\left(X\right)\geq t\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{|\varphi|}\right)$?

Comment: What's $|\varphi|$? Is it the number of clauses ("verses" in you question)?

Comment: 1. If a clause $C$ contains both $x$ and $\overline{x}$, then $C$ is trivially true and you can just ignore it.
2. Your lower bound on $\Pr(\mathbb{I}_k)$ still holds. Let $x<y$ and assume that no clause contains both a variable and its negation. The probability that a random assignment satisfies a clause with $x$ literals is smaller than the probability that it satisfies a clause with $y$ literals.
3. You can conclude that there must be a truth assignment that satisfies at least $|\varphi| (1-1/|\varphi|) = |\varphi|-1$ clauses. This is not enough to prove the claim (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

The claim is false.

Let $\varphi = (x_1 \vee x_2) \wedge (\overline{x}_1 \vee x_2)  \wedge   (x_1 \vee \overline{x}_2) \wedge (\overline{x}_1 \vee \overline{x}_2)$. Here $|\varphi|=4$, each clause in $\varphi$ contains exactly $\log_2 |\varphi|=2$ distinct literals, yet $\varphi$ is not satisfiable. (This is also a counterexample if $|\varphi|$ denotes the number of variables).

You have an error in your proof when you observe that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] \ge |\varphi| \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{|\varphi|}\right) = |\varphi|-1,
$$
and use it to conclude that there must be a truth assignment that satisfies all the $|\varphi|$ clauses. You can only conclude that there must be a truth assignment that satisfies $|\varphi|-1$ clauses (you are using the fact that $\max \{y_1, \dots, y_k\} \ge \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k y_k$, this is false in general if $\ge$ is replaced with $>$).

Answer (score 3):

You haven't explained what $|\varphi|$ is, so let's guess that it is the number of clauses. So you are given a CNF $C_1 \land \cdots \land C_n$ in which each clause contains at least $\log_2 n$ distinct literals.

Any clause which contains both a variable and its negation is always satisfied, so we can remove such clauses; call them *spurious*. Suppose that the remaining clauses are $C_1,\ldots,C_m$, where $m \leq n$.

If you choose a random truth assignment, then the probability that it falsifies a non-spurious clause containing $k$ different literals is exactly $2^{-k}$. This means that a random truth assignment falsifies each of $C_1,\ldots,C_m$ with probability at most $2^{-\log_2 n} = 1/n$, and applying a union bound, this shows that the probability that a random truth assignment falsifies at least one of $C_1,\ldots,C_m$ is at most $m/n$. If $m < n$, this means that the CNF is satisfiable, since a random truth assignment satisfies it with positive probability.

If $m = n$ then this argument no longer works, and indeed you can construct counterexamples, such as:
$$
x_1 \land \lnot x_1 \\(x_1 \lor x_2) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor x_2) \land (x_1 \lor \lnot x_2) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor \lnot x_2)
$$

First of all, let us note that if *any* of the clauses $C_1,\ldots,C_n$ contains more than $\log_2 n$ variables, then the argument above does show that a random truth assignment satisfies the CNF with positive probability. Hence $k = \log_2 n$ must be an integer, and each clause contains *exactly* $k$ literals. Thus the probability that a random truth assignment falsifies each of $C_1,\ldots,C_n$ is exactly $1/n$, and so the expected number of falsified clauses is exactly $1$.

Since the expected number of falsified clauses is exactly $1$, the CNF is unsatisfiable iff *every* truth assignment falsifies *at most* one clause. Equivalently, the CNF is unsatisfiable iff every two clauses $C_i,C_j$ cannot be falsified simultaneously. A short argument reveals that the latter condition holds precisely when there is some literal $\ell \in C_i$ such that $\lnot \ell \in C_j$, a condition which is easily checked.